# Confluent Start -> Schema Registry Failed to Start

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

When I start Confluent, Schema-registry fails, preventing the process from completing successfully. This is the response I get:

```
Starting zookeeper
zookeeper is [UP]
Starting kafka
kafka is [UP]
Starting schema-registry
Schema Registry failed to start
schema-registry is [DOWN]
Starting kafka-rest
Kafka Rest failed to start
kafka-rest is [DOWN]
Starting connect
connect is [UP]
```

When I tried to run the processes individually, zookeeper ran without problems. However, when I launched kafka, zookeeper displayed the following error:

```
Error Path:/brokers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

Then, when I attempted to run Schema registry, I was hit with a massive list of errors. I'm sure the errors all point to one small thing. Here are some of the errors (many repeat in the same long message):

1.

```
WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
```

2.

```
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor
```

3.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$ConfiguredValidatorProvider errors were found
```

4.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException
```

Some of the errors vary slightly based on location, but for the most part, these 4 errors are printed out dozens of times.

I did my best to make sure no ports were being used by other processes. I also stopped and destroyed all instances of confluent that I've created before. I've played around with Kafka on this computer before, so I theorize that that could have something to do with it, but I've made sure to close all past zookeeper and kafka instances.

I've tried to run confluent on a different computer and didn't run into any issues. Does anyone know what could be the problem? I can send the entire error message and provide any additional details.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Java 9.

I had both Java 9 and Java 8 on my computer. Turns out, Confluent was attempting to use Java 9, which isn't compatible with Confluent. When I deleted everything related to Java 9, Confluent started using Java 8, which solved the problem.

As BluePhantom pointed out, using Java 7 will also do the trick.

Comment: Java 7 is ok as well for 4.1.x.

Comment: I had to uninstall java 16 despite setting JAVA_HOME to point at java 11